# How to solve arithmetic dictionary problem?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, dynamic-programming

Given positive integers from 1 to n.

*Call sumdigit (n) is the sum of digits of n.*

*Call STR(n) as the string representing the number n.*

Arrange these numbers in order of the following:
*We have x standing before y if and only if (1) or (2) satisfy:*

```
- (1) sumdigit (x) <sumdigit (y)

- (2) sumdigit(x)=sumdigit(y) && str(x)<str(y)
```

For example:

- x = 301, y = 221 -> x comes before y (because sumdigit (x)
- x = 201, y = 30 -> x comes before y (because sumdigit (x) = sumdigit (y) and str (x)
- x = 222, y = 213 -> y comes before x (because sumdigit (x) = sumdigit (y) and str (x)> str (y))

---

Given the value of n<=10^18 and Q queries

There are two types of queries for the above problem:

**- Find the kth number in the range sorted by the above rule. (k <= n)**

- **Find the sequence number of the number k in the sequence sorted according to the above rule. (k <= n)**

---

I can solve the problem for condition (1) by using dynamic planning dp (n, sum): the number of numbers x has **sumdigit (x) = sum and x <= n**

-> `We can count the number of x numbers with sumdigit (x) <sumdigit (k).`

```
The problem I can't solve is the condition (2),
I can't think of a way to count the number of x numbers
with sumdigit(x)=sumdigit(k) and str(x)<str(k)
```

Can you help me solve the problem for the condition (2)?

I need your help!

Comment: @Primusa
I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

Let dp(d, l, s) denote the number of numbers having first digit = d (d can be 0 also), length of the number <= l and sum of digits = s.

Try to figure out the recursion. How can you use this to solve the question?